# how to build apache storm

Tags: eclipse, apache-storm

how to build apache storm.

I have downloaded storm source code version storm-0.9.0 from github.

I want to know how to setup the build environment. My aim is to study the storm source code.

first question is what IDE should be used? is eclipse fine? I didn't find any .project file in the package. But i found a project.clj file. So i assume that some form of project description is there which is written in clojure.

So i installed Leiningen plugin from Eclipse Market place.

I already have lein installed version Leiningen 2.0.0 on Java 1.6.0_29 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

Now when i import the project, i dont get any special new option, so i use the option 'General -> Existing Projects into Workspace' but it doesn't work.

what do i do???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for building Storm, see [this page](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Maven) on the Storm project's wiki.

There is some documentation available on the Storm [codebase structure](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Structure-of-the-codebase) and [implementation](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Implementation-docs), too. If you'd like to contribute to Storm development, see [Contributing to Storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Contributing-to-Storm).

You should browse the Storm wiki first, and the even more useful [storm-user](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/storm-user) discussion group.

As for the raccomended IDE -- any IDE is fine, as long as you configure it correctly (setup the project's directory structure, etc). Check out the [Maven Eclipse plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/), it can build an Eclipse `.project` file for you with a single command:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure with Leiningen but you can definitely go for `Maven`. Its easy to build and should get you started quickly. Checkout [this](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Maven) for more on maven with storm. For IDE you can for sure go with `Eclipse`.